# Include a JavaScript library in a JSP file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I'm trying to use JavaScript functions from the a JavaScript library in my JSP file to display the result on a web-browser page, but it seems like the inclusion didn't work.

I actually put the .js file corresponding to the library in the WEB-INF folder and added the following line in the JSP file to include it in it :

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jsgl.min.js"></script>
```

I successfully managed to use the library in a simple HTML file, that's why I don't understand why this doesn't work.

EDIT :

[image]

Comment: Is the path in `src` correct? Is that where the actual javascript file is located? Maybe check the name of the file is correct as a sanity check.

Comment: did you try src="/WebContent/js//jsgl.min.js"

Comment: @Rupesh Yes and it doesn't work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

Put the JS file in a folder under web content (but *not* WEB-INF) like [WebContent]/js/jsgl.min.js, and use the following in the JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Explanation**

JSP files are compiled by the server, then processed to send data (typically HTML) back to the web browser.  A `<script>` tag is a HTML tag that gets interpreted by the browser, not by the servlet container. So the browser sees that in the HTML then *makes a new request* to the server for the JavaScript file in the `src` attribute.

**The src attribute is relative to the URL that the browser asked for, not to the path of the JSP on the server.**

So as an example, let's say:

- The browser asks for a page at `http://example.com/SomeWebApp/some-resource`
- The servlet container internally forwards the request to a JSP at `/WEB-INF/jsp/somepage.jsp`
- The response sent to the browser contains the script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="./jsgl.min.js"></script>` (as in your question)
- The browser sees the URL `./jsgl.min.js` and resolves it *relative to the URL it has asked the server for* (which in this case was `http://example.com/SomeWebApp/some-resource` - note there is no trailing '/') so the browser will request the JS file from `http://example.com/SomeWebApp/jsgl.min.js`*.  This is because the relative URL in the script tag's src attribute starts with a '.'.

Another answer suggested putting the JS file in a 'js' folder and changing the script tag to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>`.  Using the same original page URL as in the example above, the browser would translate this src URL to `http://example.com/js/jsgl.min.js`.  Note that this is missing the "/SomeWebApp" context path.

The best solution therefore is indeed to put the JS file in a static folder like /js/jsgl.min.js, but to use the following in the JSP script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>
```

The JSP will translate the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` bit into the current context path, making the code portable (if you redeploy the webapp with a different context path, it will still work).  So the HTML response received by the browser will be (again, sticking with our example above):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SomeWebApp/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>
```

The browser will now resolve that relative URL to the correct target.

__

*If the original URL had a trailing slash = i.e., was `http://example.com/SomeWebApp/some-resource/`, the JS URL would be `http://example.com/SomeWebApp/some-resource/jsgl.min.js`

Comment: I tried what you proposed but it still doesn't work :/ @daiscog

Comment: I'm working in localhost, might this be the origin of the problem ?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem.  Your browser will still resolve relative URLs as normal.  Just to confirm:  Your script file is located in the `WebContent/js/` folder and the URL in your browser begins with `http://localhost/YourWebApp/...`?

Comment: That's fine, it shouldn't be a problem.  So the issue is either the URL in the script tag is wrong, or the JS file isn't where you expect it to be.  What URL is being delivered to your browser in the script tag's src attribute?  (Right-click on the page in your browser and click "view source" or "view page source" or something similar, find the script tag, check the URL.)   If you paste that URL into your browser, do you get a 404?

Comment: Also, I don't know whether Eclipse will automatically update the built webapp after you've moved files around, so you may need to redeploy the web app (clean & build or something similar).

Comment: I did all of this, the issue seems very weird :/

Comment: So you checked the URL delivered to the browser in the script tag and can browse to that URL manually?

Comment: Sorry I must have made a mistake, I just tried your method again and it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Static resources should be put outside the WEB-INF folder (as you would typically not allow web access to its content).

You could put the file under webapp/js/, then change your script import to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>
```

In addition to being good practice, this is good as it is not relative to the location of the JSP file.

Comment: I don't have a webapp folder, I'm using Eclipse, I tried similarly to what you  said, by adding a 'js' folder in WebContent then I replaced my import script by yours but it still doesn't work.

Comment: 'webapp' referred to the root folder of your web app. Typically, the default name in eclipse dynamic web projects is 'WebContent'. So the file should be under 'WebContent/js/' and the script tag in jsp as suggested above.

Comment: Well. Did you change the jsp script tag's attribute to [src="/js/jsgl.min.js"]?

Comment: Yes, it's what I dit @Ernest Kiwele

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>` won't work as it's missing the context path of the web app.  Use `<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jsgl.min.js"></script>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Files in WEB-INF are inaccessible.
```

You may put them under webapp and try accessing as mentioned above.